After running nodes with all configs as per the docs, I cannot get ETH Balance in my local BESU Blockchain network
I am developing a private Besu network with QBFT Consensus mechanism. I am following the docs exactly like here
After running all 4 nodes when I import the wallet from QBFT_Config_File.js in my Metamask or any other wallet, I am unable to see any balance in the accounts. Where I should see 200 Eth or 9000 ETH in both accounts.
please help. I need to move on ASAP.

So I have solved the issue.
I was putting same account addresses in alloc object as in the BESU docs. When I used my own account addresses(freshly generated in MM) and put them in Genesis file before starting the bootnode, it got the balance.
Very strange behavior BTW. Those addresses in BESU Docs must also work but nevertheless, I got it solved and running.
